# spring batch configuration not working properly

Tags: spring-batch

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

public class MyDataFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<MyData> {

    @Override
    public MyData mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        MyData myData = new MyData();
        
        // Assuming that the order of fields in MyData matches the order in the CSV files
        myData.setFileIdentifier(fieldSet.readInt(0));
        myData.setName(fieldSet.readString(1));
        myData.setAge(fieldSet.readInt(2));
        myData.setEmail(fieldSet.readString(3));

        // Additional logic based on the file identifier
        int fileIdentifier = myData.getFileIdentifier();
        switch (fileIdentifier) {
            case 10:
                // File 1 specific mapping logic
                break;
            case 11:
                // File 2 specific mapping logic
                break;
            case 12:
                // File 3 specific mapping logic
                myData.setStreet(fieldSet.readString(4));
                break;
            // Add more cases for other file identifiers if needed
        }

        return myData;
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MultiCsvFileReader multiCsvFileReader;

    @Autowired
    private ItemWriter<MyData> itemWriter;

    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(myStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                .<MyData, MyData>chunk(1)
                .reader(multiCsvFileReader)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.TokenizerLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MultiCsvFileReader implements ItemReader<MyData> {

    private final byte[] file1;
    private final byte[] file2;
    private final byte[] file3;

    private int currentFileIndex = 0;

    public MultiCsvFileReader(byte[] file1, byte[] file2, byte[] file3) {
        this.file1 = file1;
        this.file2 = file2;
        this.file3 = file3;
    }

    @Override
    public MyData read() throws Exception {
        byte[] currentFile = getCurrentFile();
        if (currentFile != null) {
            MultiResourceItemReader<MyData> multiReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
            multiReader.setResources(new Resource[]{new ByteArrayResource(currentFile)});
            multiReader.setDelegate(createFlatFileItemReader());
            return multiReader.read();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] getCurrentFile() {
        switch (currentFileIndex) {
            case 0:
                currentFileIndex++;
                return file1;
            case 1:
                currentFileIndex++;
                return file2;
            case 2:
                currentFileIndex = 0;  // Reset to read file1 again in the next iteration
                return file3;
            default:
                return null;  // No more files to read
        }
    }

    private FlatFileItemReader<MyData> createFlatFileItemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<MyData> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLineMapper(createLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<MyData> createLineMapper() {
        PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<MyData> lineMapper = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<>();

        Map<String, LineMapper<MyData>> lineMapperMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Create a line mapper for each file identifier
        lineMapperMap.put("10*", createFile1LineMapper());
        lineMapperMap.put("11*", createFile2LineMapper());
        lineMapperMap.put("12*", createFile3LineMapper());

        lineMapper.setLineMappers(lineMapperMap);

        return lineMapper;
    }

    private LineMapper<MyData> createFile1LineMapper() {
        TokenizerLineMapper<MyData> tokenizerLineMapper = new TokenizerLineMapper<>();
        tokenizerLineMapper.setTokenizer(createFile1Tokenizer());
        tokenizerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new MyDataFieldSetMapper());
        return tokenizerLineMapper;
    }

    private LineMapper<MyData> createFile2LineMapper() {
        TokenizerLineMapper<MyData> tokenizerLineMapper = new TokenizerLineMapper<>();
        tokenizerLineMapper.setTokenizer(createFile2Tokenizer());
        tokenizerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new MyDataFieldSetMapper());
        return tokenizerLineMapper;
    }

    private LineMapper<MyData> createFile3LineMapper() {
        TokenizerLineMapper<MyData> tokenizerLineMapper = new TokenizerLineMapper<>();
        tokenizerLineMapper.setTokenizer(createFile3Tokenizer());
        tokenizerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new MyDataFieldSetMapper());
        return tokenizerLineMapper;
    }

    private DelimitedLineTokenizer createFile1Tokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"fileIdentifier", "name", "age", "email"});
        return tokenizer;
    }

    private DelimitedLineTokenizer createFile2Tokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"fileIdentifier", "age", "email"});
        return tokenizer;
    }

    private DelimitedLineTokenizer createFile3Tokenizer() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"fileIdentifier", "email", "street"});
        return tokenizer;
    }

    private class MyDataFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<MyData> {

        @Override
        public MyData mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) {
            MyData myData = new MyData();
            myData.setFileIdentifier(fieldSet.readInt("fileIdentifier"));
            myData.setName(fieldSet.readString("name"));
            myData.setAge(fieldSet.readInt("age"));
            myData.setEmail(fieldSet.readString("email"));
            myData.setStreet(fieldSet.readString("street"));
            return myData;
        }
    }
}
In
```

I have a spring batch code as above to read from 3 different csv files. This is not working . an suggestions? I have a spring batch code as above to read from 3 different csv files. This is not working . an suggestions? I have a spring batch code as above to read from 3 different csv files. This is not working . an suggestions?

Comment: @user22962724 Can you please edit your question so we know what "not working " means. Are you getting exceptions, or empty files etc?